# IndexedDB - Storing and Retrieving Videos

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I'm trying to make an application that stores and retrieves Video files to and from IndexedDB. However, I am having issues while retrieving in Firefox and while storing in Chrome. I'll post the code:

```
(function () {
    // IndexedDB
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.OIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB,
        IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.OIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction,
        dbVersion = 1.0;

    // Create/open database
    var request = indexedDB.open("videoFiles", dbVersion);
        var db;
        var createObjectStore = function (dataBase) {
            // Create an objectStore
            console.log("Creating objectStore")
            dataBase.createObjectStore("earth");
        },

        getVideoFile = function () {
            // Create XHR
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                blob;

            xhr.open("GET", "day_the_earth_stood_still.ogv", true);
            // Set the responseType to blob
            xhr.responseType = "blob";

            xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log("Video retrieved");

                    // Blob as response
                    blob = xhr.response;
                    console.log("Blob:" + blob);

                    // Put the received blob into IndexedDB
                    putEarthInDb(blob);
                }
            }, false);
            // Send XHR
            xhr.send();
        },

        putEarthInDb = function (blob) {
            console.log("Putting earth in IndexedDB");

            // Open a transaction to the database
            var transaction = db.transaction(["earth"], "readwrite");

            // Put the blob into the dabase
            var put = transaction.objectStore("earth").put(blob, "video");




            // Retrieve the file that was just stored
            transaction.objectStore("earth").get("video").onsuccess = function (event) {
                var vidFile = event.target.result;
                console.log("Got earth!" + vidFile);
                console.log('File Type: ' + vidFile.type); /// THIS SHOWS : application/xml

                // Get window.URL object
                var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                // Create and revoke ObjectURL
                var vidURL = URL.createObjectURL(vidFile);

                // Set vid src to ObjectURL

                var vidEarth = document.getElementById("earth");
                vidEarth.setAttribute("src", vidURL);




                // Revoking ObjectURL
                URL.revokeObjectURL(vidURL);
            };
        };

    request.onerror = function (event) {
        console.log("Error creating/accessing IndexedDB database");
    };

    request.onsuccess = function (event) {
        console.log("Success creating/accessing IndexedDB database");
        db = request.result;

        db.onerror = function (event) {
            console.log("Error creating/accessing IndexedDB database");
        };

        // Interim solution for Google Chrome to create an objectStore. Will be deprecated
        if (db.setVersion) {
            if (db.version != dbVersion) {
                var setVersion = db.setVersion(dbVersion);
                setVersion.onsuccess = function () {
                    createObjectStore(db);
                    getVideoFile();
                };
            }
            else {
                getVideoFile();
            }
        }
        else {
            getVideoFile();
        }
    }

    // For future use. Currently only in latest Firefox versions
    request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
        createObjectStore(event.target.result);
    };
})();
```

Problem 1(Firefox): In Firefox, the line console.log('File Type: ' + vidFile.type); above shows "application/xml" while GETTING a video file (mp4, ogv, webm) and so the Video tag says "video format or mime type is not supported". 
However when I GET an image file like png it shows "image/png" and works well if the src of an img tag is set.

Problem 2(Chrome): In Chrome, both image and video are not even getting stored into the IndexedDB. At the following line:

```
var put = transaction.objectStore("earth").put(blob, "video");
```

Uncaught Error: DataCloneError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 25  is thrown.

I am new to IndexedDB and have no clue on how to solve this. All I need to do is store video files into indexedDB, retrieve it and show in Video tag.

The HTML is shown below:
(mp4):

```
 <div class="myVidDiv">
    <video  id="earth" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.42e01e, mp4a.40.2" controls>  </video>
 </div>
```

(ogv):

```
 <div class="myVidDiv">
    <video  id="earth" type="video/ogg" codecs="theora, vorbis" controls></video>
 </div>
```

Also tried without "codecs" attribute. Nothing works. I've been stuck with this for dayss together... Couldn't find any working example via google as well. Someone kindly help me with this.

Comment: For the problem with Chrome, are you sure the object store was actually created?

Comment: Im pretty sure that I have the required code that'd create it pal.. do we have ny other way of checking it ?

Comment: Have you tried using `add` instead of `put`? It appears `put` [isn't supported yet in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108012).

Comment: Yeah I have tried that Max.. Exact same error:

Comment: Actually, it's storing blobs that's still unsupported in Chrome. Sorry. You may want to use the filesystem API instead, and fallback storing the blob.

Comment: Oh is it? Thx for the info Max. But this is for an assignment of mine and use of indexedDB is mandatory. thts the crux of the assignment. So atleast in Firefox, do u have any clue on why the blob data type retrieved from DB is "application/xml" and not sumthing like "video/ogg" or "video/mp4" which is causing the HTML5 Video element to say "video format or mime type is not supported" .. ?

Comment: What's the Content-Type header sent by the server when you retrieve the video via XHR?

Comment: Max, I added the below :   function handler () {

                console.log(this.getResponseHeader('content-type'));
        }
 xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
... it returns "null"

Comment: console.log('xhr Response type: ' + xhr.response.type);               I could see that even before storing into DB, the response from xhr is of type "application/xml" for a video file. however it is "image/png" for a png image file... i dun have a clue why it considers a video file as of type "application/xml"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll try to sum up what it came out from the comments.

**1. Firefox**

It seems that, originally, the `Blob` object you get from the AJAX request has content type application/xml, because that's what you get in response from the server. It can be a problem of misconfiguration.

If you have access to the HTTP server's configuration, it may be solved quite easily. If it's Apache, you can simply add this line:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
```

Save, restart Apache and you should be ok. If you can't change the server's configuration, you'll have to change the `Blob`'s content type in order to match the desired one:

```
blob = xhr.response.slice(0, xhr.response.size, "video/ogg");
```

Note that this could be memory expensive because you're making a copy of a (probably) large file, but `xhr.response` should be sent to garbage after a couple of steps.

**2. Chrome**

It seems that Chrome still [doesn't support `Blob` and `File` storing](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108012).

It also seems that they've already fixed the problem, but haven't deployed the fix yet. I wonder what they're waiting for :[

**UPDATE**: as of July 1st, 2014, Chrome dev [supports storing blobs](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/07/Blob-support-for-IndexedDB-landed-on-Chrome-Dev) into IndexedDB. It's expected to land soon on the stable channel.

Comment: Max thanks a lot for ur time.. But it still is "application/xml".. :( blob = xhr.response.slice(0, xhr.response.size, "video/ogg");             console.log(blob.type); // this is still application/xml.. Same error with Video element                                                                 this thing is driving me crazy!!

Comment: I think Google is pushing FileSystem API rather than blob in IndexedDB.

Comment: @user2104377 What about trying to clone it? `blob = new Blob([xhr.response], "video/ogg");`

Comment: @user2104377 You could override the mime type using overrideMimeType() function which was introduced as part of the spec for XMLHttpRequest LEVEL 2

Answer (score 1):

```
let request = window.indexedDB.open("videoDatabase", 1);

request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
  let db = event.target.result;
  let objectStore = db.createObjectStore("videos", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
};
```

Add a Video to the Database:

```
function addVideo(videoBlob) {
  let request = db.transaction(["videos"], "readwrite")
                    .objectStore("videos")
                    .add({ video: videoBlob });

  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    console.log("Video added to the database");
  };

  request.onerror = function(event) {
    console.error("Error adding video to the database");
  };
}
```

Retrieve a Video from the Database:

```
function getVideo(videoId, callback) {
  let transaction = db.transaction(["videos"]);
  let objectStore = transaction.objectStore("videos");
  let request = objectStore.get(videoId);

  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    let videoBlob = event.target.result.video;
    callback(videoBlob);
  };

  request.onerror = function(event) {
    console.error("Error retrieving video from the database");
  };
}
```

Using Blob for Video Data:

Make sure to convert the video data into a Blob before storing it and use the URL.createObjectURL() method to create a URL for the video when retrieving it.

```
// Example of converting video file input to Blob
let input = document.getElementById("videoInput");
let videoBlob;

input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  let file = input.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function() {
    videoBlob = new Blob([reader.result], { type: file.type });
  };

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});
```

Example Usage:

```
// Assuming db is the IndexedDB database
addVideo(videoBlob);

// Retrieving the video
getVideo(1, function(videoBlob) {
  let videoUrl = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
  // Use the videoUrl to display or work with the video
});
```